# Java Spring - two qualified beans depending on another bean

Tags: java, spring

I am configuring two beans using annotations. The annotations look like this.

```
@Bean
@Qualifier("bean1")
@DependsOn(value = "masterbean")
```

With a different qualifier for the second bean.

The bean called "masterbean" just has a `@Bean` annotation.

The problem comes when I try to use the beans later on. I use them with code like this:

```
@Bean
MyClass myClass(@Qualifier("bean1") AnotherClass anotherClass)
```

Checking with a debugger it looks like only one of the two beans are initialized. i.e. the `@DependsOn` will only start up one bean.

Any ideas what I can do here?

Comment: Since you're not using `bean2` anywhere, why do you expect Spring to initialize it?

Comment: I do a second call like the first one. @Bean
MyClass myClass(@Qualifier("bean2") AnotherClass anotherClass)

Comment: And that code is in `masterbean` or a fourth bean? Please create a complete example will all relevant parts.